# LINQ to SQL execution time is 50x longer than SSMS SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, linq-to-sql, ssms

I have an asp.net app that uses Linq to SQL.

One query from the app was timing out (over 30 seconds to execute).  I increased the CommandTimeout of the DataContext, and it did complete in 45 seconds.

I copied the Linq to SQL generated SQL from SQL Profiler to SSMS and executed it using the same user credentials as I am using in my app, and I got a sub-second execution time.

I am using a new DataContext to execute the query, so the query is running in its own transaction.

My connection string looks like this:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=False; user id=MyUser; password=@#$%^&*
```

Anyone have any ideas why I could be getting such different results?

Here is the SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t1].[MatchCount], [t1].[RequestId], [t1].[Site], [t1].[Client]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[RequestId]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[MatchCount], [t0].[RequestId], [t0].[Site], [t0].[Client]
    FROM [dbo].[ReportingRequestsSubsetWithMatches] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[Finish] < @p0) AND ([t0].[Finish] > @p1)
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p2 + 1 AND @p2 + @p3
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 datetime,@p2 int,@p3 int',@p0='2013-02-02 00:00:00',@p1='2013-02-01 00:00:00',@p2=10,@p3=10
```

Comment: Bad query plan is cached for the `SET ANSI_WHATEVER* ON` options you have when using LINQ to SQL vs. what's in SSMS.

Comment: Is the asp.net app running on the same environment as the SQL server? How big is the dataset that is being returned? is it possible that the subsequent execution of the query was optimised/cached by SQL? i.e. if you run it again from LINQ is it still slow?

Comment: The site and DB are on my local machine, so they are both hitting the same environment as closely matched as possible.  I have reproed the problem many times on the server and run the query many times in SSMS, with consistent results.

Comment: It is definitely LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Can you put up your linq query so we can have a look?

Comment: @JTew SQL is now in the question

Comment: Sorry, I meant the linq, I understand the the sql generated by linq works correctly but there might be something in the linq query that causes issues.

Comment: Hello, I'm experiencing the same problem here, only I'm using Entity Framework.  Did you ever find a satisfactory answer/workaround?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the code with the timer you use to compare times? I guess you're not only measuring the connection time in the LINQ case.

Comment: @Guillaume86 - I'm stepping through execution in debug mode.  Just stepping over the query execution is what's taking all the time.

Comment: @Shaul How much rows is it returning? Don't forget LINQ has to instanciate an object by row (you can try to disable ObjectTracking to see if it's better). Not related but your question mention a transaction by new DataContext, it's not the case AFAIK

Comment: @Guillaume86 - 28 rows returned, 6 columns per row.

Comment: In the bounty message you say: "Query was copied and pasted from SQL profiler to SSMS. It's huge; too big to put in the question - lots of aggregates & group-bys." so the query in the question is not the actual query? I'd still like to see the LINQ query, some operations trigger a N+1 behavior (enunerating on a GroupBy for example).

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you having the issue on?

Answer (score 5):

Compare the SET options for SSMS and your LINQ sessions:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id in (@@SPID, @LINQSESS)
```

(replace @LINQSESS with your Linq session id)

---

[ARITHABORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx) is often the culpit, see if this solves your issue:

```
new SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yeah. This is always the same problem. SET options. Always the same, 10 questions a week.

Comment: sp_updatestats and DBCC FREEPROCCACHE made negigible difference to me.  The MSDN page linked here is too verbose to find anything useful.  Can you please summarize: How do you compare SET options between SSMS and Linq2Entities? @usr - ping in case you read this first :-)

Comment: The set options on SSMS can be checked at menu Tools-> Options-> Query Execution-> SQL Server-> Advanced/ANSI.

Comment: Yep, it was arithabort.  You get the bounty!  Thanks!

Comment: @usr, I'm back again, and totally exasperated.  Setting `arithabort` on worked... temporarily.  Now I've got another query that, complex as it is, runs in 1 sec in SSMS, but 27 sec in Linq2Entities.  I have set arithabort on.  All other options are identical.  Why, oh why, oh why?  I just can't face the prospect of rewriting this entire thing in a SP!