# Why does LINQ/SQL connection in C# take over 10 times as long as running stored procedure in sql studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that runs in 4 seconds. When i try to access it through c# LINQ or SQL connection it takes over 40 seconds.

**SQL**

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SummarizeRevenue_V10]
    @SalesLocation = 1,
    @District = 0,
    @ReportStartDate = N'1/1/2015',
    @ReportEndDate = N'1/31/2015',
    @SelectionReportType = 1,
    @SummarizeBy = N'Driver',
    @Threshold = 62.50
```

**LINQ**

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
dc.CommandTimeout = 600;
var foo = dc.SummarizeRevenue_V10(1, 0, DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015"), DateTime.Parse("1/31/2015"), 1, "Driver", 62.50m);
```

**SQL Connection**

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fluidsConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SummarizeRevenue_V10", conn){CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@SalesLocation", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            command.Parameters.Add("@District", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ReportStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015");
            command.Parameters.Add("@ReportEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Parse("1/31/2015");
            command.Parameters.Add("@SelectionReportType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            command.Parameters.Add("@SummarizeBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Driver";
            command.Parameters.Add("@Threshold", SqlDbType.Money).Value = 62.50m;
            conn.Open();
            command.CommandTimeout = 600;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

We have run this on multiple computers, with the same results. Obviously the LINQ statement came from a larger program. We took it out, and made it to where the code you see is the code we ran. We put a break point at the LINQ and execution statements and one after the statement. When the program broke for the statement we continued the program and started our count. We have tried changing the LINQ statement to a SQL command (as you can see).

Comment: LINQ to SQL was never intended to be performant.  A dedicated stored procedure will always be faster than an ORM.

You can gain some increase in speed if you turn off change notifications in your Data Context but that will still be slower than the LINQ variant.

Comment: I understand LINQ to SQL is not the best performing option. But using the sql command code i am getting similar results. Is a difference of over 40 second or ten time expected when running a stored procedure from c#

Comment: Have you tried using SQL profiler to verify the same SQL is sent to the server and compare its execution time?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15912670/59849

I've seen a lot of examples where setting ARITHABORT ON greatly improved performance in linq-to-sql.

Comment: Run this command first `SET ARITHABORT ON` then run your real command.

Comment: @Peter this isn't just for LINQ to SQL.

Comment: My mistake regarding linq-to-sql - I mis-read the tags. Still, the solution I linked to would apply to EF as well, just using a slightly different syntax.

Comment: the Arithabort worked... It is set to on when i look at the db in SQL  Management Studio... odd. Thank you very much

Comment: It looks like classic parameter sniffing http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html Read the article. It explains what `ARITHABORT` does, why it seems to help and how to figure out whether the problem is indeed caused by parameter sniffing.